# Setting out a list of variables in Salt and then importing into another file

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

Is it possible to set out a list of salt variables such as:

```
{% set foo = '1234' %}
{% set bar = '10.1.1.2' %}
{% set environment = salt['grains.get']('env') %}
```

and then import them into separate .sls file and use them like so:

```
foo_value = {{ foo }} # sets foo to '1234'
bar_value = {{ bar }} # sets bar to '10.1.1.2'
etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best fit should be the [`import`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import) feature.
You can store the file with variables as described in question and then import them like:

```
{% from 'yourfile.jinja' import foo with context %}
{% from 'yourfile.jinja' import bar with context %}
{% from 'yourfile.jinja' import environment with context %}
```

Or alternatively you can add all of them to an array:

```
{% set vars = {
  'foo': '1234',
  'bar': '10.1.1.2',
  'environment': salt['grains.get']('env'),
  }
%}
```

And then import it at once:

```
{% from 'yourfile.jinja' import vars with context %}
```

Best practices on using variables (and import) are described at [Salt Best Practices page](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/best_practices.html).